# Use memcached for laravel on multiple sites

Tags: laravel, memcached

On a server I have about 25 websites running the same laravel based backed. I want to change the session&cache driver from file to memcached. But this causes a cached data mixup. e.g. I see the menu from site 1 on site 2.

How can I use memcached on multiple sites?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only possible way of doing this would be to have unique cache keys for each website.

It could be based on a unique website identifier (id or url). 
I think the logic to retrieve the cache keys could also be encapsulated a bit. In my current setup, I have something a little similar whereby the cache keys are different depending on the locale.

```
protected function getCacheKey($key, $locale = null)
{
    $prefix = '__app_cache_';
    $suffix = $locale ? "_$locale" : '';

    return $prefix . $key . $suffix;
}
```

For example, your logic could be something like this:

```
protected function getCacheKey($key, Website $website)
{
    $prefix = '__app_cache_';
    $suffix = "_{$website->id}" : '';

    return $prefix . $key . $suffix;
}
```

and then to get the `menu` cache key, you would do something like this:

```
$cache->getCacheKey($menu, $website);
```

This is, obviously, just an example and needs to be adapted to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea of a prefix I found a nicer solution for Laravel. But somehow I cant find this on the internet.

In the cache.php file I added an extra key options with the memcached prefix option that is available in the memcached documentation:

```
'memcached' => [
    'driver'  => 'memcached',
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100
        ],
    ],
    'options' => [
        Memcached::OPT_PREFIX_KEY => "websitename",
    ],
],
```

Now all the sites can run without issues

Answer (score 0):

Brother, If you haven't used Memcached with Laravel then I would prefer to go with Redis, It has more good speed in easy to work with Laravel.

Comment: @Patrick also you can use this with multiple key based the key pattern, Like Domain name and key and unique id, somedomain_key_uniqueID.